# Multiple variables assignment using SET and SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I use the following t-sql code for assign to variable a value obtained from select statement

```
 DECLARE @cfMitt nvarchar(16)

 SET @cfMitt = (SELECT CfMittente
    FROM Messaggi
    WHERE IDMessaggio = @IDMessaggio)
```

If I want use multiple assignement I try with the following  code, but something is wrong:

```
DECLARE @cfMitt nvarchar(16)
DECLARE @cfDest nvarchar(16)

SET @cfMitt, @cfDest= (SELECT CfMittente, CfDestinatario
FROM Messaggi
WHERE IDMessaggio = @IDMessaggio)
```

Where is the error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Set` only assigns one value at a time.

You should use

```
   SELECT @cfMitt = CfMittente, 
          @cfDest = CfDestinatario
   FROM Messaggi
   WHERE IDMessaggio = @IDMessaggio
```

Answer (score 1):

Variable declaration can also be;

```
DECLARE @V1 VarType, @V2 VarType,...
```

Assignment;

```
SELECT @V1 = C1, @V2 = C2,...@Vn = Cn
FROM [Table]
WHERE Conditions
```